# Does the absence of a license file in client side code give people any rights?

Tags: licensing

I am wondering if the absence of a license file (not having one at all) in code exposed to the client side provides any rights to copy or modify the code? Specifically, in reference to client-side JavaScript code packaged as a single page app.

Do people have no rights to my code unless I give them rights via a license, or do they have all rights until I specify limitations?

Comment: @MichaelT - I did not think to search for "default" license and was unable to find something like that when I looked. That's pretty much what I was looking for.

Comment: Its not uncommon to have a situation where you need to be familiar with the names of the existing questions in order to find one.  Marking this as a 'yes, this is a duplicate' helps the next person who finds your question find the other one.  You may also find additional material in the [linked questions](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/26548?lq=1) to that one.